# ¿Como ignoro un directorio para pull?

Tags: git

se me presenta la siguiente situacion:
Yo tengo un sistema que funciona con apache y php, uso hojas de estilo en less, para simplificar tengo una estructura de carpetas asi:

```
rootDir/index.php
rootDir/img/
rootDir/css/
rootDir/less/
rootDir/js/
```

En el servidor de prueba funciona todo lo mas bien, cuando hago un cambio y esta listo lo pusheo a el servidor git.
Ahora bien, cuando quiero hacer un pull desde el servidor de produccion para hacer efectivos esos cambios en el otro entorno obtengo **todos** esos archivos.
El problema es que el directorio `less` no hace falta ya que estos se compilan en css, pero al hacer pull estos son traidos de todas formas. Quisiera que la estructura del servidor de produccion sea asi

```
rootDir/index.php
rootDir/img/
rootDir/css/
rootDir/js/
```

He intentado tanto modificar el arrchivo .gitignore en mi servidor de produccion para ignorar el directorio, lo cual no funciono, y tambien ejecutar el comando `git update-index --assume-unchanged less/*`, pero cuando ejecuto el comando `git update-index --refresh` este me avisa de que todos los archivos less necesitan una actualizacion.
Puedo borrarlos manualmente siempre que haga un pull, pero me gustaria evitarlo si es posible.

---

Edito mi pregunta para aclarar lo siguiente:
A mi me interesa que todos los archivos esten versionados, i.e. que el servidor git los almacene y no sean ignorados en un push, solo me interesa que no esten en el entorno de producción.

Comment: Tienes que evitar subirlos. El `.gitignore` debería estar en el servidor de prueba. Ahora deberías sacarlos del control de versiones en tu máquina de desarrollo (con `git rm --cached`) y hacer un `push` nuevo para que desaparezcan también del repositorio. El siguiente `pull` ya no las bajará.

Comment: Pero sí los quiero tener controlados por si quiero hacer un pull en otro entorno de prueba ¿Necesitaria entonces dos repositorios distintos en mi servidor git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respuesta corta sería:

```
less/
```

> Tenga en cuenta que si usa solo `less` ignorarán los archivos llamados less, mientras que si usa `less/` ignorara el directorio como tal.

`Git` no ignora los archivos mientras lo tira. En su lugar, debe agregar estos archivos en sus archivos `.gitignore`, para que no se comprometan y se envíen a repositorios remotos.

Si estos archivos ya están en su repositorio remoto, entonces debe eliminarlos usando por ejemplo:

```
git rm --cached comun/main-local.php

git rm --cached comun/parametros-local.php
```

Si desea eliminar el directorio común, entonces en `.gitignore` agregar:

```
comun/**
```

Y elimina el directorio:

```
git rm --cached -r comun
```

- Remover (rm).
- Indice (--cached).
- Recursivamente (-r).

Ahora haz un nuevo `commit` y `push`. Estos archivos se eliminarán del repositorio remoto también.

> Aquí te dejo estos enlaces que pueden ayudarte también:
>
> - [4 maneras de ignorar archivos con Git](http://codethug.com/2013/09/20/4-ways-to-ignore-files-with-git/) (Traducir del Inglés)
> - [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) (Traducir del Inglés)

Comment: Pero yo quiero que los archivos esten versionados en mi servidor git, solo no quiero que sean descargados al hacer un pull

Comment: Si bien la respuesta no da el restultado que busco, me parece que es lo que mas se acerca a lo que necesito, ya que estuve investigando y realmente no encontre una manera de obtener lo que quiero con git. de modo que la doy por valida, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es especificar en tu archivo `.gitignore` (si no existe puedes crearlo) el directorio que deseas se ignore, en este caso el directorio:

```
/less
```

el archivo `.gitignore` debe localizarse dentro de:

```
rootDir/
```

Revisa la [documentación acerca de .gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

---

Modifica el archivo .gitignore en tu copia local y lo subes al servidor.